# Weekday(...) shows wrong weekday

Tags: excel

I live in Europe. Week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday.
Today is Friday, the 5th day of the week.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkgqR6jJ76GcWrCJozpQ?e=mRH7Ab

=Weekday(Today();2)

shows Thursday as weekday, not friday.

Why?
And why shows Returntype 1 (or omitted) Friday, it should show Saturday (6th day of the week)?

And what is the difference between Returntype 2 and 11?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you did there, but the row with 'weekday Number of actual date' is highlighted correctly since with return_type 2 Monday should be '1', Tuesday '2' upto Friday which would be '5'. Also, the options 11-17 were introduced in Excel 2010 whereas the other options allready existed. No real difference I don't think.

Comment: Have you checked your excel setting where you can define Sunday or Monday as the first day of the week?

Comment: @SolarMike kan you give me a hint where I find this setting? I checked all the settings and couldn't find. 5 will get formatted as Thursday in my Excel. Yesterday I upgraded to office 365.

Comment: Not Excel settings - it is in the system settings - at least on my OS. Along with the choice of calendar - I have Gregorian selected.

Comment: @SolarMike I found it in windows settings. It was correct. Even when changing it, it did not change in Excel only in the calendar in the task bar.

Comment: @SolarMike when you open the example file, (I included at screen picture), does it show the weekdays like on the picture or correctly?

Comment: I'm not opening any example file... However, If I put 2 as the final argument then it shows Thursday and if I put 1 then it shows today as Friday, so works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241713/discussion-between-prema-and-solar-mike).

Comment: `WEEKDAY` is returning the correct result. If you format 5 as ddd, you are actually formatting the date 5 days after 31.12.1899 which is the 5th Jan 1900, which was a Thursday.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. Just link directly to the actual date and then format as dddd, or use the TEXT function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WEEKDAY` is returning the correct result in that cell - i.e. 5.

If you format 5 as ddd, you are actually formatting the date 5 days after 31.12.1899 which is the 5th Jan 1900, which was a Thursday.